# What do I need to do so the function isspace work in C

Tags: c, compilation

When I try to compile my C program with cc I get a warning that I have an implicit function declaration isspace. Isn't this part of the standard C library? Which import do I need to do so my function runs properly?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Cheers

Comment: Did you include `ctype.h`?

Comment: jschultz410 already answered the question, so this is just a tip. On a Linux, BSD, or MacOS system, 'man isspace' would have solved your question. Just a tip for future problems of this sort.

Answer (score 10):

You need:

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

Answer (score 9):

You need `#include <ctype.h>`.

However make sure you read the documentation carefully. Its interface is unintuitive, for historical reasons.

It's designed to work only on a value from `0` to `UCHAR_MAX` (usually 255) -- the same sort of value that is returned by the `getchar()` function. For example:

```
int ch = getchar();
if ( isspace(ch) )
```

**Do not use it with a `char`**.  If you have a `char` that you want to check for whitespace, it must be converted to be in the expected range; e.g. by a cast to `(unsigned char)`:

```
char ch = 't';
if ( isspace( (unsigned char)ch ) )
```

The same goes for all of the other `is*` functions in `ctype.h`